# What governor limits impact Apex Describe methods?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, dynamic-apex, describes

Are there any governor limits, or considerations that I should be aware of when using Apex Describe methods?  So for example, the author of this blog post uses the structure below to get the record type instead of doing a soql query.

http://www.jonathanbroquist.com/retrieving-sobject-recordtypeid-dynamically-with-salesforce/

```
//Generate a map of tokens for the sObjects in your organization
Map gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

//Retrieve the describe result for the desired object
DescribeSObjectResult result = gd.get('Account').getDescribe();

//Generate a map of tokens for all the Record Types for the desired object
Map recordTypeInfo = result.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
system.debug('RECORD TYPES:' + recordTypeInfo);

//Retrieve the record type id by name
String recordTypeId = recordTypeInfo.get('RECORDTYPE_NAME').getRecordTypeId();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As mentioned, describe limits have been removed entirely. Just for completeness, there are a few remaining limits that *are* affected by these describe calls, but consumption is *negligible*. These limits are `Heap Space` and `CPU Time`. The numbers below are for my org, so mileage will vary. I doubt the numbers would ever get high enough to be a concern.

**Methodology**

You need separate approaches (though one execution is sufficient) to derive the measures that follow. All of this was run in `Execute Anonymous` with logging levels set to `NONE` except for `Apex`, which was at `DEBUG`.

```
Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    Map<String, SObjectType> describe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
system.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - start);
// divide above number by 100 (or whatever number of iterations you use) to get ms elapsed

Integer heapBefore = Limits.getHeapSize();
Map<String, SObjectType> describe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize() - heapBefore);
// divide the above by Limits.getLimitHeapSize(); for percentage of heap used
```

**Consumption**

1. `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`
   `CPU Time`: ~7ms
   `Heap Space`: ~0.3%
2. `Schema.SObjectType.getDescribe()`
   `CPU Time`: ~0.002ms
   `Heap Space`: ~0.001%
3. `Schema.SObjectField.getDescribe()`
   `CPU Time`: ~0.38ms
   `Heap Space`: ~0.001%
4. `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByName()`
   `CPU Time`: ~0.2ms
   `Heap Space`: ~0.0001%

**Analysis**

If you are getting the *global* describe more than once, cache it. It should be quite simple to cache, and the heap consumption is likely worth the tradeoff even if the number of calls is <50.

For *object* describes, every 1000 calls (in a single transaction) consume only 2ms (out of 10s), so you don't need to pay much attention unless you are expecting >100K calls. Caching 1000 fields will only consume 1% of your heap space, so that's not a huge concern either. I recommend you use whatever makes your code cleanest.

For *field* describes, you only get three calls per millisecond, so the calculus is a little different. Now 1000 calls consume an amount of time that is perceptible by humans. However, the cache rate is the same. If you are describing the same field many times, consider caching.

For *record type* describes, the CPU situation is much the same as with fields. You get five calls per millisecond, so you don't necessarily want to call it thousands of times. But caching it is very inexpensive. You should be able to cache the describes for every single `RecordType` without consuming 1% of your heap.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  If I'm thinking about writing a code base with lots of dynamic apex, how does that scale to the CPU /Heap limits?

Comment: @user11235813 I started typing it out as a comment and then realized I should just edit my post with ramifications. Let me know if that's what you're trying to get at.

Comment: YES! this is exactly what i'm looking for! Where are you getting this from??

Comment: @user11235813 Edited again to reflect the approach.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, the CPU time is significantly high in my orgs. Average CPU time for Schema.getGlobalDescribe() is ~57ms in sandbox and ~41 in production. Even in my developer edistion instance, the average CPU time is  ~22ms. Are you aware of any such cases?

Comment: @Avinash Sounds like you have a lot of objects.

Comment: @AdrianLarson My Developer Edition org has only 5 custom objects. Even it is taking ~22ms CPU time for Schema.getGlobalDescribe() call.

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit for Describe Call in Salesforce.

As per the below document, There were few limits before Summer'14 release and it was remove post Summer'14 release.

For more information:-
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer14/New+Apex+Enhancements