# Are individual object describe calls expensive enough to justify static cache?

Tags: apex, performance, describesobject

Supposing we have a method that executes logic dynamically depending on the SObject type like the following one:

```
public class TestDescriber {

    public static void callMeManyTimes(SObject record) {

        String sObjectName = record.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

        ...
    }
}
```

Assuming this method would be called multiples times per transaction and many of those calls will involve the same SObject type, will the `getDescribe()` calls be expensive enough to justify having a static cache in the class to avoid calling the describer multiple times?

```
public class TestDescriber {

    private static Map<SObjectType, String> namesPerSObjectType = new Map<SObjectType, String>();

    public static void callMeManyTimes(SObject record) {

        String sObjectName = getSObjectName(record.getSObjectType());

        ...
    }


    private static void getSObjectName(SObjectType sType) {

        if (!namesPerSObjectType.containsKey(sType)) {
            namesPerSObjectType.put(sType, sType.getDescribe().getName());
        }

        return namesPerSObjectType.get(sType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What governor limits impact Apex Describe methods?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121620/what-governor-limits-impact-apex-describe-methods)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you